# How can I replace dollar signs with brackets?

Tags: python, string, replace

I have written the following source code to replace dollar signs with square brackets:

```
text= r"mu-the mean direction $\mu \in [-\pi,\pi)$.   kappa-a concentration parameter $\kappa > 0$.  "

    def replace_dollar(self, text):
        new_text = ""
        flag = False
        for ch in text:
            if ch == '$':
                if flag is False:
                    new_text += "["
                    flag = True
                else:
                    new_text += "]"
                    flag = False
            else:
                new_text += ch
        return new_text


if __name__ == '__main__':
    new_text = replace_dollar(text)
    print(new_text)
```

**Output**

```
mu-the mean direction [\mu \in [-\pi,\pi)].   kappa-a concentration parameter [\kappa > 0].
```

Is there any more efficient technique?

Comment: The only practical alternative is to keep using `text.find('$')`, but I don't think that's any more efficient.

Comment: Why don't you use regexp?

Comment: @snahor, coz, I don't know RegEx.

Comment: How long are your actual texts, and how many dollar signs do they have? (Asking to make my benchmark more realistic.)

Comment: @Manuel, not more than 50 dollar signs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a version using your current logic, but more readable.

```
text= r"mu-the mean direction $\mu \in [-\pi,\pi)$.   kappa-a concentration parameter $\kappa > 0$.  "

bracket = "[]"    # Index this string with values True/False, which are 0/1
right = False     # Indicates to use right bracket (or not)

while '$' in text:    # In each iteration, replace the left-most occurrence
    text = text.replace('$', bracket[right], 1)
    right = not right    # Switch between left and right brackets 
    print(text)          # This is for tracing only
```

Output:

```
mu-the mean direction [\mu \in [-\pi,\pi)$.   kappa-a concentration parameter $\kappa > 0$.  
mu-the mean direction [\mu \in [-\pi,\pi)].   kappa-a concentration parameter $\kappa > 0$.  
mu-the mean direction [\mu \in [-\pi,\pi)].   kappa-a concentration parameter [\kappa > 0$.  
mu-the mean direction [\mu \in [-\pi,\pi)].   kappa-a concentration parameter [\kappa > 0].
```

Comment: the problem with your code is, it can't handle multiple characters. For example, what if I want to replace dollar signs with `[[[` and `]]]`  ?

Comment: First, your post asks for a solution to substitute single characters, not strings.
Second, it's a simple fix: replace that value of `bracket` with a two-element sequence of your desired pairings.  In the extension you cite, you should use `bracket = ( "[[[", "]]]" )`

Comment: Darn, I tried `for _ in range(text.count('$') // 2): text = text.replace('$', '[', 1).replace('$', ']', 1)` hoping it would be faster, but it was a bit slower (about 10% in my benchmark).

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions. Maybe not as efficient (you'd have to measure), but certainly tidier and less error prone.

```py
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'\$(.*?)\$', r'[\1]', text)
'mu-the mean direction [\\mu \\in [-\\pi,\\pi)].   kappa-a concentration parameter [\\kappa > 0].  '
```

Edit: Pre-compile the RE to improve efficiency if you'll be using it repeatedly:

```py
>>> dollar_to_brackets = re.compile(r'\$(.*?)\$')
>>> dollar_to_brackets.sub(r'[\1]', text)
'mu-the mean direction [\\mu \\in [-\\pi,\\pi)].   kappa-a concentration parameter [\\kappa > 0].  '
```

Comment: Thanks, I accidentally pasted the original input string as the result

Comment: Considering OP will be using it in a helper, it would be cool if you also add `re.compile`.

Comment: Can your source code handle multi-character brackers? For example, what if I want to replace dollars with `[[[` and `]]]` ?

Comment: @user366312 Yes, just replace `[\1]` with `[[[\1]]]`. The `\1` indicates everything between the dollar signs so you can put anything you want around it (e.g. `<body>\1</body>`).

Comment: @snahor Does that help much?

Answer (score 1):

Another regex way:

```
import re
from itertools import cycle

def replace_dollar(text):
    return re.sub(r'\$', lambda _, c=cycle('[]'): next(c), text)
```

Benchmark results with the question's example text:

```
8.41 us  original
0.82 us  Prune
4.66 us  Woodford
4.09 us  Woodford2
2.12 us  Manuel
```

And with the text multiplied by 10 (so that it has 40 dollar signs - OP said they have *"not more than 50 dollar signs"*, so maybe that's a realistic test):

```
91.60 us  original
30.75 us  Prune
27.33 us  Woodford
27.41 us  Woodford2
11.79 us  Manuel
```

Benchmark code, [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVRNi9swEL37VwxpFsupk252SykLbg@F3gqFLvSQBKMok7WILRlZZrO/Ph3JSmyTNtQQrMy8efM8H6rfbKHV4@fanE57oyuwskJpQVa1NhYM1sht5D37VgmrddmcnTU3VvIyumA7nLRoRjjxJkqMoh3uQRv5IhUvmcWjTZ4iCI/C19yZIIPJ5GLdl/yFLN952WBv1AZEAVKBC@gp3CP3zpVlEE/jsSd4PaNsOsprxEjKe9KymvwVE4Q9mxav/Ph/zJubzONP/jftkFIUF7dB2xp18Xa1/2lahcPCbw0XB/Q1XwU51J7CjvK/FrJEV8/rioeGudeCBqXkAhkB0zPxyrNtUlgmvbKQQGnbnaOB3l7rb6131OjdUG4AGVw07ZaZeD1li9nXZO0ymni1Xm7o4PFjjgdPksJOlyU3udV50NdkxCV0VdMXjviSccbrwKDgOucPrlosb6umiJJX2x2HPAWR@e1g8WoTJ0/UsaNlIhlxblGJouLmwAJlqLuZVO3cFggVchIpDQortYLpumphTd1azde1TOmXTBcUduB1zecchFYClTXco2mJeYW0shTnEfAF7h2@Gwi39A0lOy9u2o1Reqluf3pIw@dHPvIdfNPGaVLYNN6Cx5r@Dsi6OkXnrXa53JT5nP2Y8aahC8VbuwC34B3XOdOvGnHnz6qttvQtGSzvYTaDjxfy3DEbrl6QPQ4unht5famJqZKKdfcgCzcec8jQozSkzLpXksCHYBkR1UYqy@K7xcMe2gZiuANmYQZL/EQUjm@R54o6kef9snRBNAaDETid/gA):

```
from timeit import repeat
from functools import partial
import re
from itertools import cycle

def original(text):
        new_text = ""
        flag = False
        for ch in text:
            if ch == '$':
                if flag is False:
                    new_text += "["
                    flag = True
                else:
                    new_text += "]"
                    flag = False
            else:
                new_text += ch
        return new_text

def Prune(text):
    bracket = "[]"
    right = False
    while '$' in text:
        text = text.replace('$', bracket[right], 1)
        right = not right
    return text

def Woodford(text):
    return re.sub(r'\$(.*?)\$', r'[\1]', text)

def Woodford2(text, dollar_to_brackets=re.compile(r'\$(.*?)\$')):
    return dollar_to_brackets.sub(r'[\1]', text)

def Manuel(text):
    return re.sub(r'\$', lambda _, c=cycle('[]'): next(c), text)

def benchmark():
    text = r"mu-the mean direction $\mu \in [-\pi,\pi)$.   kappa-a concentration parameter $\kappa > 0$.  "
    funcs = original, Prune, Woodford, Woodford2, Manuel

    # Correctness
    expect = original(text)
    for func in funcs:
        assert func(text) == expect

    # Speed
    number = 10 ** 4
    for _ in range(3):
        for func in funcs:
            t = min(repeat(partial(func, text), number=number)) / number
            print('%.2f us ' % (t * 1e6), func.__name__)
        print()

benchmark()
```